# In i3blocks, how can a dynamic text be clickable?

Tags: i3

(From the project introduction) "[i3blocks](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks#click) executes your command lines and generates a status line from their output."

As per [the i3blocks config file](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks#blocks), here is the syntax to get the time in the status :

```
[time]
label=any string or glyph 
full_text=any string or glyph 
command=date "+%a, %b %_d %Y %I:%M%P"
interval=5
```

And here is how you execute a GUI command on click:

```
[click]
full_text=Click me!
command=gsimplecal
color=#F79494
```

Both work, but how do I combine the two, that is, being able to click on the time to pop up the calendar? I tried this:

```
[clickable_time]
full_text=date "+%a, %b %_d %Y %I:%M%P"
command=gsimplecal
interval=5
```

But it doesn't work (the date string command is displayed, and gsimplecal gets executed every 5 seconds) so obviously a workaround must be found..?

Comment: my setup uses the status_command, which involves generating and stream-parsing json. i'd be very interested in a better option as well

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a few months old but i just came across a similar requirement where i want to show the volume in the bar but want to open `pavucontrol` on click to configure audio settings. This is what i ended up with that works.

```
[volume]
command=if [ $button ]; then pavucontrol; else pulseaudio-ctl full-status | awk '{ printf "%i%\n", $1 }'; fi
interval=1
label=<span color="#ffb86c"> </span>
```

checking if `$button` exists (a click) and doing something different, otherwise get the volume (the text that gets placed into the value)