# isblocks.conf create onclick event (open firefox with URL)

Tags: shell-script, scripting, i3, rss-aggregator

I have this block in `/etc/i3blocks.conf`

```
[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 50
color=#00FF00
interval=300
```

I'd like to click on this block and open `firefox` with the correct URL.

Here is a block that opens firefox with URL.

```
[clickme]
align=center
full_text=Click me!
command=/usr/bin/firefox --new-tab https://www.stackexchange.com/
```

I don't know how to combine it together. [Here](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks#click) is a documentation.

[Here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/edit-and-direct-continuously-output-from-program-rsstail-4175546492/) is how to get a link:

```
rsstail -l -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | sed -n 2p
```

I probably will need to save a link of `rsstail` to some "block variable" and than use it in the command.

So far, I have this solution:

```
[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT # | head -c 40
color=#00FF00
interval=300

[clickme]
align=center
full_text=*
command=firefox --new-tab `rsstail -l -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | sed -n 2p`
```

It opens the link, when I click `*`. So, I'm not clicking on the title, but on the `*` next to the title. But the link may not be associated with the title, and this is what I don't want. I need to pass the link to some kind of variable (e.g. block variable or environment variable, whatever possible).

Answer (score 1):

This was quite harder than I thought it would be.  You have to create a separate bash script to make it happen.  I presume you have correctly setup paths in your i3blocks `config` file.

### Create a bash script for the feed

You need to create a bash read the information you need to display the topic and when clicked if would open correct web page.

**Warning:** There is a hidden limitation which could cause issues if you are not aware of it.  The URL length can be maximum of 32 chars long as the [instance variable](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks/blob/01a4f4a9ca1e3d0b3c95d1d62000ad8506bdff1a/include/block.h#L50) is defined that way.  If you want to use longer URL you need to use a URL shortener. (also mentioned in the script!)

I have created a bash script called `rss` and it is placed within a `rss` directory.  My path is: `~/Build/i3blocks/blocklets/rss/rss`.

In the i3blocks config I have a global command:

`command=$SCRIPT_DIR/$BLOCK_NAME/$BLOCK_NAME`

and in the i3 config I have:

```
bar {
       # status_command i3status
       status_command SCRIPT_DIR=~/Build/i3blocks/blocklets i3blocks
}
```

The `rss` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# WARNING: This has a LIMIT of 32 characters for now!
# If your URL is longer you should use an URL shortener
# Caused by https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks/blob/01a4f4a9ca1e3d0b3c95d1d62000ad8506bdff1a/include/block.h#L50

# if BLOCK_INSTANCE is empty try a default value page instead
rss_url="${BLOCK_INSTANCE:-https://news.ycombinator.com/rss}"

if [[ "${url}" = "" ]]; then
  exit 1
fi

# get the title to show on bar
rss_title=$(rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u "${rss_url}" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 40)
# the link to web page that will be displayed
rss_link=$(rsstail -l -n1 -1 -N -u "${rss_url}" | sed -n 2p)

if [[ "${rss_title}" = *404* ]]; then
  echo "${rss_url}"
  echo "${rss_url}"
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi

if [[ "${BLOCK_BUTTON}" -eq 1 ]]; then
  /usr/bin/firefox --new-tab "${rss_link}"
fi

echo "${rss_title}"
echo "${rss_title}"
echo ""
```

### Add a block to your i3blocks config file

```
[rss]
instance=https://news.ycombinator.com/rss
label=
interval=300
```

**Note:** The label is an Unicode symbol for the RSS, I don't know why unix SE does not see it.

I have decided to share how the result looks at my end.  First I saw the RSS feed and then I clicked on it:

[image: RSS feed on the bar and after clicking o it]

Comment: I need to make the first block in my question clickable. You created another block, so that the `rsstail` have to run twice and during time the link can change (not to be associated with the correct title)

Comment: @xralf I see well the logic is the same I'll adjust the answer so the first block will be clickable.  But it will open multiple tabs as it gives `Google I&#x2F;O 2023`.

Comment: @xralf Perhaps I don't fully understand the question...

Comment: Yes, I need to use the first block, which displays RSS title and than create for the same block onclick event (or use some variable, e.g. local block variables, or environment variables, whatever that is possible) with the link associated with the title.

Comment: @xralf I finally understand it now.  That is longer than this, I'll delete the question and edit it tomorrow.

Comment: @xralf I have finished rewriting it.  It was trickier than I thought first.

Answer (score 1):

Include onclick to start firefox with the url.

```
[rss]
command=rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 50
color=#00FF00
interval=300
markup=pango
onclick=/usr/bin/firefox --new-tab "$(rsstail -l -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | sed -n 2p)"
```

`markup=pango` enable the use of pango markup in the block's text, it is not required for basic text formatting but it is useful.

`onclick` event launches firefox with the url and running the rsstail command and extracting the second line of the output

Reload i3blocks to apply the changes `pkill -RTMIN+10 i3blocks`

Click on the rss block, it will start firefox with the correct url.

[i3blocks-scripts](https://github.com/topics/i3blocks-scripts?o=asc&s=stars)

[i3blocks-gaps pango markup color for label works with color name](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/b4tjri/i3blocksgaps_pango_markup_color_for_label_works/)

[20 Using the code from others to change your i3 look – i3 blocks](https://www.arcolinuxd.com/using-the-code-from-others-to-change-your-i3-look-i3-blocks/)

[i3blocks-contrib](https://app.bountysource.com/teams/i3blocks-contrib/issues?tracker_ids=20342863)

[In i3blocks, how can a dynamic text be clickable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626376/in-i3blocks-how-can-a-dynamic-text-be-clickable)

[Clickable i3block?](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/5a6q63/clickable_i3block/)

Try with separate block:

```
[start_firefox]
command=/usr/bin/firefox --new-tab https://news.ycombinator.com/
interval=once

[rss]
command=echo "<a href='signal:USR1:start_firefox'>$(rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 50)</a>"
color=#00FF00
interval=300
markup=pango
```

Without `<a href></a>`:

```
[start_firefox]
command=/usr/bin/firefox --new-tab https://news.ycombinator.com/
interval=once

[rss]
command=$(rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 50)
color=#00FF00
interval=300
markup=pango
```

Without `head -c 50` and `pango`:

```
[start_firefox]
command=/usr/bin/firefox --new-tab https://news.ycombinator.com/
interval=once

[rss]
command=$(rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT)
color=#00FF00
interval=300
```

[head -c 50 might cause a problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/745154/515538)

Check if the commands run alone without error:

```
rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 50
```

```
rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

Other errors:

- Check the path for `/usr/bin/firefox`
- Is `--new-tab` recognized, try with and without
- Change the `interval` value of `300`
- Is the `rss` block in the correct format
- Does `rsstail` command working correctly
- Is `iconv` necessary
- Can you run the commands separately
- What version do you have
- Do you see the blocks if you run `i3blocks` in the terminal
- Did you edit the `~/.config/i3/config`

Comment: I added your block to my `/etc/i3blocks.conf` and then `i3-msg restart` and Now I have error `Error: status_command process exited unexpectadly (exit 1)`

Comment: try again with 2 blocks

Comment: can you run the rsstail command alone to make sure there is no error? rsstail -n1 -1 -N -u https://news.ycombinator.com/rss | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT | head -c 50

Comment: Your new answer only opens `news.ycombinator.com` after `i3-msg restart` it won't display anything in i3 bar.